# Playing a music backwards using MediaExtractor

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-mediacodec, audio-player, mediaextractor, android-music-player

I want to create an app playing music backwards that uses the Android MediaExtractor to decode audio and connect backwards

As I can not get the MediaExtractor to move it backwards, I tried to cut it up to a certain byte size from end, flip it, play it, and cut next end and play so on.

In order to do this, we need to use `MediaExtractor.seekTo` to rewind forward, but the position to rewind is ambiguous. I tried to `seekTo` calculated Micro Seconds with sample rate and the certain byte size, but when using `MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC` flag, the connection part is slightly shifted and noise occurs.

So I think this problem can be solved if I can know the location of the Byte being sync, or if I can `seekTo` in bytes unit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure is the connection part slightly shifted and not a buffer underrun error due to the fact that seek needs to flush data before moving the head?

Answer (score -1):

since you want it in reverse couldn't you use SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC for a better match instead of SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, but there is almost no difference between them. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: goto pure java and write the file to temporary storage and get the exact properties that way. for eg use tarosDSP or realtime processing using the beadsproject (https://github.com/orsjb/beads/)